# Downcasting to access additional events and methods in a subclass

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to specialise a base class by adding new events and methods to it. For example, class B inherits from class A. However, if in code I hold a reference to my class B instance as its base type, A. Am I required to downcast everytime I need to access something from it from B, e.g. subscribe to EventB1, or call MethodB1?

```
if (obj is B) 
{ 
  B m = (B)obj;
  m.EventB1 += EventHandlerB1; 
}
```

Also, if I have a switch statement in my base class as above. Is it bad practice to add more cases to it in B?

```
Class A
{
  public event EventHandler EventA1

  public void MethodA1()
  {
    //some code
  }

  protected virtual void ProcessWorkItem(workItem type)
  {
    switch (type)
    {
      case workItem.A1:
        ..
        break;
      case workItem.A2:
        ..
        break;
      case workItem.A3:
        ..
        break;
    }
  }
}

Class B : A
{
  public event EventHandler EventB1

  public void MethodB1()
  {
    //some code
  }

  protected override void ProcessWorkItem(workItem type)
  {
    base.ProcessWorkItem(type);

    switch (type)
    {
      case workItem.B1:
        ..
        break;
      case workItem.B2:
        ..
        break;
      case workItem.B3:
        ..
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I required to downcast everytime I need to access something from it from B, e.g. subscribe to EventB1, or call MethodB1?

Absolutely. This should tell you there's a design smell here. It doesn't mean it's *necessarily* bad, but it should at least prompt you to consider whether there's a cleaner approach.

> Also, if I have a switch statement in my base class as above. Is it bad practice to add more cases to it in B?

It's hard to tell without knowing more about what it's trying to do. It's not clear whether using composition instead of inheritance would help you here, but it's usually something worth thinking about. You may also want to consider using interfaces - both `A` and `B` could implement the same interface, with `B` composing an `A` if required. Maybe. It's hard to tell :)

Comment: I believe that it would be interesting to understand why does OP has a specialized class but keeps its reference as the base class. It makes me think if the inheritance is really necessary, after all. If he is primarily working with events, maybe some interfaces would be better suited.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I've editted my original post. I forgot to override ProcessWorkItem in class B and call the base method first.

Comment: @bobbo: Thanks, I've removed that piece of my answer. It's still not really clear what the context is though - it's hard to recommend any particular patterns without more information.

Comment: @AndreCalil: Agreed. I'll add the idea of interfaces into my answer - I nearly did that before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to access methods of type B, you'd have to cast your object to type B.
If you absolutely do not want to do that, you could use Reflection to invoke the repsective method. However I'd not recommend that without knowing more about what you want to do.

Also, what comes to mind related to the events: if you want to invoke an event, you have to do that from code implemented in the class it is declared in.

Regarding the switch: I think that depends. First thing... I'd use an override and then, depending on what this function does/serves, call base or not.

Regards,
Martin

```
Class A
{
  public event EventHandler EventA1

  public void MethodA1()
  {
    //some code
  }

  protected virtual void FireEventA1()
  {
    if (EventA1 != null)
      EventA1(new EventArgs());
  }


  protected virtual void ProcessWorkItem(workItem type)
  {
    switch (type)
    {
      case workItem.A1:
        ..
        break;
      case workItem.A2:
        ..
        break;
      case workItem.A3:
        ..
        break;
    }
  }
}

Class B : A
{
  public event EventHandler EventB1

  public void MethodB1()
  {
    //some code
  }

  protected virtual void FireEventB1()
  {
    if (EventB1 != null)
      EventB1(new EventArgs());
  }

  protected override void ProcessWorkItem(workItem type)
  {
    base.ProcessWorkItem(type);
    switch (type)
    {
      case workItem.B1:
        ..
        break;
      case workItem.B2:
        ..
        break;
      case workItem.B3:
        ..
        break;
    }
  }
}
```